# <sync-adapter> element is not recognized

Tags: android, xml, android-resources, android-syncadapter

When I try to implement the [Sync Adapter Framework](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html#DeclareSyncAdapterManifest) in my application the following error appears before running the app :

```
No resource identifier found for attribute 'contentAuhority' in package 'android'
```

My `syncadapter.xml` resource file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:accountType="example.com"
 android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
 android:contentAuhority="my.authority"
 android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
 android:supportsUploading="false"
 android:userVisible="true" />
```

Note: `<sync-adapter>` element does not appear in suggestions (in Android studio) but `<account-authenticator>` appears.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<sync-adapter xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:accountType="example.com"
 android:allowParallelSyncs="false"
 android:contentAuthority="my.authority"
 android:isAlwaysSyncable="true"
 android:supportsUploading="false"
 android:userVisible="true" />
```

Comment: What is the difference between your xml file and my file ?

Comment: Check for android:contentAuthority spelling